# Maximum likelihood estimation - why is $\mathcal{L}$ not the joint pdf?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, estimation, sampling

Here's an excerpt from my notes:

---

Define the likelihood function: $$\mathcal{L}(\vec{x};\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i;\theta)$$

Where $f$ is the pdf of the distribution we're sampling the $x$'s from. Caution: the likelihood function $\mathcal{L(\vec{x};\theta)}$ is not the same as the joint pdf $L(\vec{x};\theta)$

---

Could someone explain to me where this "caution" comes from? Is it purely because the samples were not assumed independent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likelihood function $\mathcal L$ is not the same as the joint pdf $L$ because they are functions of different variables. The likelihood function $\mathcal L$ is a function of the parameter $\theta$ for a fixed value of the observations $\vec{x}$ but $L$ is a function of the observations $\vec{x}$ for a fixed value of the parameter $\theta$. This is why I prefer to write $\mathcal{L}(\theta;\vec{x})$ instead of $\mathcal{L}(\vec{x};\theta)$.

The general definition of the likelihood function when $\vec{x}$ admits a joint pdf is actually in terms of the joint pdf:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta;\vec{x}):= L(\vec{x};\theta)
$$
but in case of independence this simplies to $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n f(x_i;\theta)$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, they are two functions given by the same formula, but with different things being variables? (At least in the indep. case)?

Comment: @DepeHb: Yes, the likelihood function and the _joint_ pdf give the same value for fixed $\theta$ and fixed $\vec{x}$. This is by definition of the likelihood function in terms of the joint pdf (this _also_ holds for the dependent case). They just differ because the one is a function of the observations $\vec{x}$ and the other is a function of the parameter $\theta$. The likelihood function $\mathcal{L}$ is often used to find the MLE, i.e. the value $\hat{\theta}$ that maximizes $\theta\mapsto \mathcal{L}(\theta;\vec{x})$ when $\vec{x}$ is held fixed.